# How exactly is the value of DC in an AC circuit, given by the RMS of the AC

Tags: electricity, electric-current

How and WHY does the RMS of current gve us the equivalent DC?

I've been though this answer here:-[root mean square for dc](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45858/root-mean-square-value-for-dc.)
but it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an arguably limited equivalence, but a convenient one. The **power dissipation** in a linear resistor R due to an alternating current $I\cdot\sin(\omega t)$ is the same as the power dissipation in the same resistor due to a direct current with the corresponding r.m.s. value, which is $I/\sqrt 2$.

To see why, just consider the instantaneous power dissipation rate in the alternating case, that is $I^2\cdot R\cdot \sin^2(\omega t)$ . With the math equivalence $\sin^2(\omega t) = (1 - \cos(2 \omega t))/2$ , of which the mean value is of course just $1/2$, the mean power dissipation rate is $(I^2/2).R$, i.e. the same as what would be produced by a direct current $I/\sqrt 2$. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! So it's basically just defined that way, right?

Comment: @fhhh : Well if attention is confined to questions of power dissipation then it's a physical equivalence and not just a definition. But for any other, non-power, purposes, if the rms value is taken to be equivalent to the a.c. value then yes, I guess you could call it conventional and a matter of definition.

Comment: Ok.THanks a lot!

Comment: Do you mind if I accept this answer in a day? I't answers my doubt, but I'd like to wait for a bit

Comment: That's fine and you're welcome. HTH!

Comment: @fhhh, Re, "So it's...just defined that way..?" No. "defined" means that somebody just decided what some word should mean, and everybody else agreed. Terry S. showed you the _mathematical reason_ why it _has_ to be that way.