# differentiate between v(rms) and V(avg/dc) of an Ac signal

Tags: electrical-engineering

Please differentiate between  v(rms) and V(avg/dc) of an Ac signal .  Why do we use rms and why is vrms called effective value; why is vp not so called or (v(avg))? And why we use v rms to calculate power (avg)?

Comment: _Why we use V rms to calculate average power?_  Because it gives the right answer!  I'm sorry, I don't know the mathematical explanation of _why_ it gives the right answer, but giving the right answer _is_ the reason why we use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Justification of root mean square](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/141158/)

Comment: See also http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41779/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/146113/

Answer (score 1):

The average voltage of a pure AC signal is 0V.  That's not a lot of use.

Vrms is widely used because it ensures that an AC voltage produces the same heating effect in a resistor as the equivalent DC voltage.  This also means it will produce the same light from an incandescent lamp.